# How to connect GSON lib in AndroidStudio

Tags: android, gson

When I add in gradle  `compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'`
I have this problem

> Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
>       Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/gson/JsonSerializer;
>
> Error: Execution failed for
>   task':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.> 
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
 compileSdkVersion 22
 buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"
 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.jsonmyapp.ars.gson_4"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
 compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
 androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
 testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

 compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40151068/6893465

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable multiDex

```
defaultConfig {
   // Enabling multidex support.
   multiDexEnabled true
}

// also add this in your android block. This is use for multidex

dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
    incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

More info on multidex:

[Android MultiDex Page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/multidex/MultiDex.html)

[Configure MultiDex](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)

Answer (score 0):

its not GSON problem, try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40651235/6747577)

First try this to clean and rebuild your project.

Then open File --> Invalidate Caches / Restart , Click on the blue button Invalidate Caches / Restart.

If this didn't work with u try this solution:

1- add to your
    build.gradle(Module.app)

```
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

2- add this in dependencies:

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

2- In manifest file add this

```
<application android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
```

It works with me Correctly.

And I think the Problem is that you are using a lot of Libraries in the Gradle ,You might have exceeded the 64K Reference Limit.